# Business object not found in "Choose your business object" dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I created a ASP.NET Web application **DemoGrid** with a page Default.aspx. Then I created a Class Library **EmployeeManager** with a class **EmpMan**. The code is as under:

```
namespace EmployeeManager
{
    public class EmpMan
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public List<EmpMan> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            List<EmpMan> employeeList = new List<EmpMan>();
            EmpMan emp = new EmpMan();
            emp.EmployeeName = "arjun";
            emp.EmployeeID = 1;
            employeeList.Add(emp);


            return employeeList;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to populate my gridview with data of **GetAllEmployees**
But when choosing a new data source, no business object other than **DemoGrid.Default** is shown in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the Solution and it worked like charm.

Comment: Although the reason for this issue seems to be a performance issue from VS side. Rebuilding did not help me out but restarting my VS did.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood, you are not getting the class you have defined in your class library, something like this:-

[image]

You need to add the `reference` of your class library in your web application project for that, and make sure your class library is compiled, you will then see the class present in your class library in dropdown of object data source:-

[image]

Comment: You could also add following attribute to your class.    <DataObject()> _

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure which dropdown you are referring to, but I'm guessing that you are viewing the page with the grid in Desgin mode.

In any event, the classes you create are not going to show up there automatically.

A typical way to do this is by coding in the page behind for the web page.

You would have something like:

MyGrid.DataSource = GetAllEmployees();
MyGrid.DataBind();

Comment: I am trying to populate gridview using ObjectDataSource